# How can i make a bulk upsert query with Pymongo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using Pymongo to perform some upsert queries on a for loop, but since the queries are taking too much time to execute, i tried to do the same task using a bulk write operation. However, i'm not familiar with the syntax, and i'm having some problems:

According to the docs, i need to define an array of operations, so i did the following:

```
Queries = [[{'Unix': 1596873600.0}, {'$set': {'Unix': 1596873600.0, 'O': '11586.08000000', 'H': '11801.72000000', 'L': '11562.17000000', 'C': '11775.52000000', 'V': '9066.55659000', 'market': 'BTCUSDT'}, 'upsert': True}], [{'Unix': 1596888000.0}, {'$set': {'Unix': 1596888000.0, 'O': '11775.52000000', 'H': '11808.27000000', 'L': '11706.39000000', 'C': '11738.10000000', 'V': '6628.24686700', 'market': 'BTCUSDT'}, 'upsert': True}...]]
db['myCol'].bulk_write(Queries)
```

This gives me a `is not a valid request` error. Can anyone help me out on the syntax of this query?I'm using PyMongo. Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try this [Bulk Write Operations](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html#bulk-write-operations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the bulk operators, in your case `UpdateOne()`

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, UpdateOne

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

Queries = [UpdateOne({'Unix': 1596873600.0}, {'$set': {'Unix': 1596873600.0, 'O': '11586.08000000'}}, upsert=True),
           UpdateOne({'Unix': 1596888000.0}, {'$set': {'Unix': 1596888000.0, 'O': '11775.52000000'}}, upsert=True)]

db['myCol'].bulk_write(Queries)
```